# Acessando campos de tabela de Ligação Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redmine

PERGUNTA MODIFICADA:

Possuo uma aplicação que tem 2 tabelas: `Curso` e `Cargo` e uma Terceira tabela `curso_cargo` que faz o **`HBTM`** entre elas. Gostaria de saber como acesso um campo desta tabela `curso_cargo`, para incluir dados nele por um `text_field`?

Possuo uma aplicação que tem 3 tabelas : `Conhecimentos`, `Cargo` e `cursos_cargos`.

```
create_table :cargos do |t|
  t.integer :id
  t.string :nome
  t.text :missao
  t.text :atribuicoes
  t.text :formacao
  t.text :experiencia
  t.references :setor
  t.timestamps
end

create_table :conhecimentos do |t|
      t.string :nome
      t.timestamps
    end

create_table :conhecimentos_responsabilidades, :id => false, :force => true do |t|
      t.references :cargo
      t.references :conhecimento
      t.references :nivel
    end
```

Nesta ultima tabela , tenho um campo nivel_id, que guardará um id de um nível para cada conhecimento cadastrado para aquele cargo.  Esse campo, ficará em uma `view` de Cargos, onde será exibido quais os conhecimentos existentes e o nível do mesmo.

Como fazer para criar o `form` , indicando que aquele `Cargo`, tem um `conhecimento` com o `nível` x?

Answer (score 1):

Você está criando a [tabela de associação](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table) `curso_cargo` sem necessidade e *quase* de forma errônea.

O Rails trabalha de forma unânime, onde a convenção está sobre a configuração – e isso só torna necessário a utilização de duas tabelas: `curso` e `cargo`. Se você precisar injetar informações *não-associativas* à sua terceira tabela (`curso_cargo`), independente de Rails ou não, você está errando – tabelas de associação servem só e somente só para associar entidades (X) à entidades (Y).

Segundo a nomenclatura da sua tabela de associação, `curso_cargo`, eu presumo que `cargo` pertence à `curso`, sendo que um ou mais cursos podem dividir o mesmo cargo. Portanto, em `/app/assets/models/curso.rb`, você ensina para `curso` que ele possui um cargo:

```
class Curso < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :cargo
end
```

E lá em `/app/assets/models/cargo.rb`, você explica que ele [o cargo] pertence à um curso:

```
class Cargo < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :curso
end
```

Feito isso, o Rails se encarregará de fazer a associação para você. Além dessa praticidade, você está trazendo à tona uma ótima – e padrão – prática.

Destacando, a sua tabela `curso` vai precisar de um `cargo_id` da seguinte forma:

```
+----+------+----------+
| id | nome | cargo_id |
+----+------+----------+
```

Para manipular isso com `x.text_field`, você pode fazer:

```
[...]

<%= f.text_field :curso, :cargo_id %>

[...]
```

Comment: modifiquei a pergunta pois havia me expressado de forma incorreta sobre o assunto.